# Knockout.js seems to be clobbering my jQuery event handlers, how rude

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Ok I've been trying to unravel this mess for a few hours now and have gotten nowhere, analogous to a dog chasing its tail.  Here's the situation.

I'm using Knockout.js for my UI, which works great by itself.  However, I'm trying to use some third party code that makes dropdowns and checkboxes look all pretty.  Actually I'm not even sure if this is a third party library or just something our designers wrote.  This code *hides* the real checkbox and replaces it with a fake `<span />` that mimics a checkbox through CSS.  The `click` event of the span triggers the `change` event of the real checkbox:

```
// this code updates the fake UI
this._changeEvent = function() {
    self.isChecked = self.$input.is(':checked');
    self._updateHTML(false, true);
    jQuery(self).trigger('change');
};

// when the user clicks the fake checkbox, we trigger change on the real checkbox
this.$fake.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    self.$input.click().trigger('change');
});

// Bind _changeEvent to the real checkbox
this.$input.change(this._changeEvent);
```

This actually works with Knockout.js, since Knockout will listen to that event handler.  In other words, when the user clicks the fake checkbox, the bound Knockout model gets updated.  However, what *does not* work is updating the model.  If I call:

```
model.SomeValue(!curValue); // SomeValue is bound to a checkbox, flip its value
```

The model gets updated, but the fake UI is not updated.  I've traced this problem down to the code in `ko.bindingHandlers.checked.update` which does the following:

```
// When bound to anything other value (not an array), the checkbox being checked represents the value being trueish
element.checked = value;
```

Basically, the `element.checked` property is set, but no events are fired.  Thus, the `_changeEvent` function is never called.  So, I've implemented my own `ko.bindingHandlers.checked.update` function, which is a copy of the built-in one.  In theory, this is all I should need to do:

```
   ko.bindingHandlers.checked.update = function (element, valueAccessor)
   {
      var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

      if (element.type == "checkbox")
      {
         if (value instanceof Array)
         {
            // When bound to an array, the checkbox being checked represents its value being present in that array
            element.checked = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(value, element.value) >= 0;
         }
         else
         {
            // When bound to anything other value (not an array), the checkbox being checked represents the value being trueish
            //element.checked = value;
            $(element).prop('checked', value).trigger('change'); // <--- this should work!
         }
      }
      else if (element.type == "radio")
      {
         element.checked = (element.value == value);
      }
   };
```

Rather than setting `element.checked`, I instead call `.prop('checked', value)` and trigger the change event.  However, this is not working.  Here's what I know so far:

1. If I remove Knockout.js from the equation, `$(element).prop('checked', value).trigger('change');` works perfectly fine.  So, knockout.js is screwing with the event some how.  Is it unbinding that event handler?
2. I've confirmed `$(element)` is the same thing as `this.$input` in the fake checkbox binding code.  I can set other expando properties on this element, and they show up.
3. I've tried a few approaches to try to debug into Knockout.js and jQuery to see if the event is still bound, however I haven't really gotten anywhere with this approach.  My *hunch* is that Knockout.js somehow replaced the `change` event handler with its own internal one, and existing bindings were removed.  I haven't found a way to confirm this yet.

**My Question:** Mainly, I'm looking for a solution to this problem.  Does Knockout.js remove existing `change` events that were there before the model was applied?  What are the next steps in debugging this code and figuring out exactly what's going on?

Comment: +1 How rude, indeed :)

Comment: Can you show your HTML also/

Comment: +1 for a well written question. Haven't delved into this (yet), but glancing over the KO source I do see that `RegisterEventHandler` in [utils.js](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/utils.js) has quite a lengthy comment about special handling of checkboxes when jQuery is also involved. Maybe that's a lead?

Comment: It works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Gphmj/1/

Comment: @Esailija - Yea, I think I'm gonna have to build a fully self-contained reproducible example.  Sigh.

Comment: How about changing the event you trigger to a custom name and listening for that instead? That way you wouldn't be conflicting with anything KO does with the `change` event...

Comment: @MichaelBerkompas - Yea, I actually sorta got that working.  I attached the function object directly to an expando property of the input tag, then called it directly.  No event handlers at all.  That works, but I'm still curious as to what's going on.  Whatever the situation, it seems to be rather complicated as any stand alone test I build does not reproduce the problem.  I think right now, I'm just looking for debugging techniques to narrow down the issue.

Comment: When using Knockout with jQuery, the order of inclusion matters. Knockout uses jQuery only if it's present when Knockout is included.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the event listeners bound to the input field, with and without KO involved? The Chrome dev tools plus jQuery Debugger (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-debugger/dbhhnnnpaeobfddmlalhnehgclcmjimi) are quite helpful. Also, if Knockout does clobber your change handler, it probably happens in the bindings `init` method; I would try to create my own binding instead of overloading the built-in and focus there.

Comment: @Jeroen - you are probably right, as the last line of comment states: "// Fix this by intecepting the handler and applying the correct checkedness before it runs."

Comment: So were any of the answers right?

Comment: @zmanc - Nope, but there's something going on outside what I've posted that messes stuff up.  I spent about 2 hours trying to build an isolated repro case and could not.  Basically, it works fine on its own but when I move the same code into my project, it doesn't work.  Unfortunately, I ran out of time and had to get back to higher priority coding so I've kinda abandoned this question.

Comment: @MikeChristensen fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than overriding the base checked handler, just create your own custom binding to update the UI.

Here's an example of a model and a custom binding to handle updating the UI:

```
var Model = function () {
    this.checked = ko.observable(false);
};

ko.bindingHandlers.customCheckbox = {
    init: function (element) {
        // Create the custom checkbox here
        $(element).customInput();
    },
    update: function (element) {
        // Update the checkbox UI after the value in the model changes
        $(element).trigger('updateState');
    }
};
```

I'll bind the model to the following HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="genre" id="check-1" value="action" data-bind="checked: checked, customCheckbox: checked" />
```

And really that's all I'll need to do.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/badsyntax/4Cy3y/

[edit] - i think i rushed through reading your question and didn't get the crux of what you were asking. I'll leave my answer here in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Try triggering and listening also for a custom event:

```
element.checked = value;
element.dispatchEvent(new Event("forcedChange"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the checkbox object as a jQuery plugin and create knockout custom bindings to bind it to your viewmodel.
I have set up a jsfiddle that does just that: http://jsfiddle.net/markhagers/zee4z/3/

```
$(function () {
    var viewModel = {
        truthyValue1: ko.observable(false),
        truthyValue2: ko.observable(true)
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

(I had to add this snippet, or my answer wasn't accepted, see the jsfiddle for the full code example).
Sorry, it looks like a lot of code, but the plugin part was originally a standalone jquery plugin, with the knockout bindings added later, some code in it has been obsoleted by the knockout bindings.
It can be put into it's own file to reduce clutter.
Creating custom bindings is documented on the knockout website.

Answer (score 0):

Just brainstorming, but was this third-party control developed using event namespaces? It could be like you suggest, that knockout and this control are fighting over the default 'change' event in some way. When I develop widgets and applications I always use event namespaces when binding events using jQuery.

Example using a 'myWidget' namespace:

```
$('#element').on('change.myWidget', function(e) {
  // handle the event
}
```

I could be completely off base though.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought. Your designers seems to trigger the click and change event in this line:

```
self.$input.click().trigger('change');
```

Couldn't that be something to try? Maybe it's bound to the click event rather than the change event? Try this in you else-statement:

```
$(element).prop('checked', value).click().trigger('change'); // <--- this should work!
```

What i have understood that .click() does: It mimics a mouseclick and at the same time triggers the click event (Duh?).

I know that sometimes (like when in a radio or checkbox) some coders are binding the event to the click rather than change since this is more likely to fire at the correct time (in IE7 the change event fires in a really weird way).

Just a thought, might be something to try out.
Hope it helps!

EDIT: 
I saw an answer about namespaces in your events and custom events. This could also help you, hope it's not a too large change.

/J.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue you're having is not due to a conflict in events from knockout and another set of code (for example, changing the CSS of the checkboxes) but due to a conflict in how the Javascript thread, and the events in the thread, are handled.

Javascript is handled in the browser as a single thread: all processes run sequentially and any event that interrupts the sequence might cause your event to fail. If you can call each of the functions independently but there is interference when you include both in your script, the onclick or onmousedown event that triggers the CSS change for the checkboxes might interfere with the knockout script. In this "single thread" all events can influence the execution of another, even mouse movement.

This (http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) example demonstrates this idea using timers but I think your current situation could be suffering from the same problem.

To solve it, you might write a short function such as:

> function doBoth(checkboxid){
>
> > $("#checkboxid").addclass("prettychecked");
> >
> > $("#checkboxid").prop('checked', true);
>
> }

The important point is that each action takes place in sequence without the possibility of a mouse event interrupting.

Hope this helps!